# Error on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, error

Error:

> `<apex:page>` is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" controller="CommunitiesLoginController" action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}"" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Can you provide context? What is the full error message and what does your VF page look like?

Comment: I have posted the code but it is not displaying..Click on Edit of the post and will see my code..I am not sure how to display this.

Comment: @sf.dev in the future, when you are adding code to your questions there is a button on the toolbar - a pair of brackets `{ }` - which will allow you to include code markup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<apex:page` tag has an extra quote in it at the end of the action attribute.

`action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}""`

Answer (score 0):

Dear Everyone,
                I have used ...  code but error is show in this page so can you help for run this code.

```
<apex:component controller="SiteLoginController" id="loginComponent">
    <apex:form id="loginForm" forceSSL="true">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
            <apex:pageMessages id="error" />
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">            
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.username}" for="username" />
                <apex:inputText id="username" value="{!username}" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password" />
                <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}" />
              <br />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!login}"
                    value="{!$Label.site.login_button}" id="loginButton" />
                <br />
                <apex:panelGroup id="theLinks">                     
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.ForgotPassword}">
                        {!$Label.site.forgot_your_password_q}
                    </apex:outputLink>                     
                    <apex:outputText value=" | "       
                        rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}" />
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.SiteRegister}"
                        rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}">
                        {!$Label.site.new_user_q}
                    </apex:outputLink>                     
                </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: Ok, Bhati     I'll check